# Why does FireError fail in C# 2012, but works in VB, while FireInformation works in both?

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio, ssis, sql-server-2012

I have an SSIS package in Visual Studio 2014, and I want to raise an error in a Script Component if any records traverse a particular path out of a 3rd party transformation.  I *WANT* to do this in C# 2012, but the FireError method gives an error:

> The best overloaded method match for 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.Wrapper.IDTSComponentMetaData100.FireError(int, string, string, string, int, out bool)' has some invalid arguments

When I try to do this:

```
    bool fireAgain = false;
    IDTSComponentMetaData100 myMetaData;
    myMetaData = this.ComponentMetaData;
    myMetaData.FireError(0, "Script Component", "Invalid Records", string.Empty, 0, ref fireAgain);
```

but if I change FireError to FireInformation, it compiles and works -- except of course I need an error raised, not an informative event.

Also, if I use Visual Basic instead of C# as so:

```
    Dim pbFireAgain As Boolean = False
    Dim myMetaData As IDTSComponentMetaData100
    myMetaData = Me.ComponentMetaData
    myMetaData.FireError(0, "Script Component", "Invalid Records", String.Empty, 0, pbFireAgain)
```

Which is, I mean, literally the same exact thing but in a different language, it works fine.  VB also works with FireInformation.

Obviously I can solve my immediate problem by using VB, but can someone tell me WHY this is this way?  It seems like a specific issue with C#.  As evidence, we have this on MSDN:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms136031.aspx

Where the Script Component version of FireError is the *only* of eight examples to not have C# *and* VB versions (the logging one is poorly formatted, but they're both there).

I'm wondering if there's a debugger configuration that threatens to run C# code in an odd way, as [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27802221/why-are-firewarning-and-fireerror-working-but-fireinformation-is-not) answered, but the error I get is at design time -- Visual Studio springs the earlier "invalid arguments" error before I compile, so it knows something is off.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may be confusing the similar but different syntax for firing error vs information events from Script Components (data flow task) versus Script Tasks (control flow). The intellisense for Component indicates that the parameter is pbCancel whereas the fireAgain corresponds to the Information Task's parameter.

## Script Component

C# Script Component example

```
public override void Input0_ProcessInputRow(Input0Buffer Row)
{
    bool cancel = false;
    bool fireAgain = false;
    this.ComponentMetaData.FireInformation(0, "My sub", "info", string.Empty, 0, ref fireAgain);
    this.ComponentMetaData.FireError(0, "My sub", "error", string.Empty, 0, out cancel);
}
```

VB Component

```
Public Overrides Sub Input0_ProcessInputRow(ByVal Row As Input0Buffer)
    Dim cancel As Boolean
    Dim fireAgain As Boolean
    Me.ComponentMetaData.FireInformation(0, "my sub", "info", String.Empty, 0, fireAgain)
    Me.ComponentMetaData.FireError(0, "I hate vb", "Error", String.Empty, 0, cancel)
End Sub
```

There's no need to explicitly specify that a parameter is By Reference since that appears to be done in the definition versus the C# requirement to specify it also on invocation. 
[ByRef vs ByVal Clarification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4383167/byref-vs-byval-clarification)

## Script Task

C#

```
    public void Main()
    {
        bool fireAgain = false;
        this.Dts.Events.FireInformation(0, "my sub", "info", string.Empty, 0, ref fireAgain);
        // Note, no cancel available
        this.Dts.Events.FireError(0, "my sub", "error", string.Empty, 0);
    }
```

VB

```
Public Sub Main()
    Dim fireAgain As Boolean = False
    Me.Dts.Events.FireInformation(0, "my sub", "info desc", String.Empty, 0, fireAgain)
    Me.Dts.Events.FireError(0, "my sub", "error desc", String.Empty, 0)

    Dts.TaskResult = ScriptResults.Success
End Sub
```

## Summary

- C# requires you to specify `ref` and `out` keywords. They are not synonyms
- VB lets you do whatever
- Error event in Components have a cancel parameter

Comment: So, I get the utility of ref and out; I take it your third note that "Error events in Components have a cancel parameter" is important to why the boolean must be an "out" parameter, rather than a ref; that is, I appreciate how to fix it, but why do the two functions (FireInformation and FireError) differ in this regard?

Comment: Also, I still maintain that the Microsoft documentation I linked to is cryptic on the topic, so I'm curious if anyone knows why.  But again, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You are passing it by `ref`, not `out`, in your C#. I don't think VB.NET needs those keywords.

Comment: So, is there a proper syntax to get the FireError working in C# that I'm missing?

Comment: I got it; billinkc had a nice example.  Still not clear on why FireError requires an "out" variable; I guess you can continue to update the boolean in a FireInformation call, but the error requires the flag to remain static... still not completely clear on why.  Does FireError