# how to write at the text which created by Configure SSIS Logs dialog box

Tags: logging, ssis, dialog

I used Configure SSIS Logs dialog box to define logging options for a package today. I checked the package, set the directry of text for logging records. I successed to output the logging records.

However, this evening, my boss order me to find out how to write something in the text. I and my boss has used the logging system for three hours, so we don't know how to use suitable. Moreover the boss required to find it immediately to only me.

the something what I want to write is that the number of record rows, just word "hello" on the top of the page, and so on.

Do you have any idea how to write something by using  Configure SSIS Logs dialog box.

Thank you for reading.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you've stated that you have enabled Logging within SSIS. When you do this, you log specific events (OnError, OnWarning, OnInformation, etc).

If you want to add your own messages into the log, then you need to add a Script Task or Component (depending on where you are logging) and use the FireX methods, where X is the event you are logging.

Samples of firing events [Why does FireError fail in C# 2012, but works in VB, while FireInformation works in both?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28906984/why-does-fireerror-fail-in-c-sharp-2012-but-works-in-vb-while-fireinformation/28907522#28907522)

Comment: i apologize to response the question.

Comment: Thank you very much. I solve my problem. I may be able to ask different questions.